# Twitter Integration Does not returning to OnActivityResult

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

After sign-in to twitter it does not come back to OnActivityResult,
I am using fragment for this twitter Integration
Here is my code

I followed this tutorial [https://docs.fabric.io](https://docs.fabric.io/android/twitter/log-in-with-twitter.html#request-user-email-address)

```
TwitterAuthConfig twitterAuthConfig = new TwitterAuthConfig(TwitterKey,TwitterSecretKey);
Fabric.with(getContext(),new Twitter(twitterAuthConfig));
```

......

```
 twitterLoginButton.setCallback(new Callback<TwitterSession>() {

        @Override
        public void success(Result<TwitterSession> result ) {
            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Twitter Result "+ result );
            Twitter.getInstance().core.getSessionManager().getActiveSession()
            TwitterSession session = result.data;
            String msg = "@" + session.getUserName() + " logged in! (#" + session.getUserId() + ")";
            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Twitter Result "+msg);
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        @Override
        public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
            Log.d("TwitterKit", "Login with Twitter failure", exception);
        }
    });
```

....

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("APP_LOG   ", "  requestCode  " + requestCode + "  resultscode:  " + resultCode + "  Data " + data);
    loginButton.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer, Twitter is not working for me because I used inside a Fragment 
so that is why it's not working, I just created new Activity now it's working

Answer (score 0):

Though you've already found a solution, I want to mention one more reason, why your onActivityResult could not be called.

It doesn't depend on whether you've implemented twitter callback handling in fragment or activity - it should work in both cases. The only difference is that in fragment implementation, you should rethrow onActivityResult event from activity to your fragment.

Another reason, why onActivityResult is not called, is that your activity immediatelly closing after calling twitter auth view. 
This may happen if your activity has **noHistory="true"** flag.